# How to manually edit testng.xml in eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Tags: eclipse, testng, suite, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

Can anybody suggest me how to manually edit TESTNg.xml file in Eclipse
Now with new version it has no option for editing.Also i created my Testng.xml my converting my code to TestNG,Then testng.xml file got created.
My classes in testng.xml are as below:

```
classes

@name       com.test.TESTNgbasics
!Test
!Suite
```

I want to add a new class which I created by no option coming

If I try to create the file manually by selecting File in General under Src then it generates a file with Node and Content headings

Comment: Can you show us what's going on? Are you not able to just open the file in the XML Editor and flip over to its Source tab?

Comment: thanks i got my solution open with is working now I tried opening it with Text editor

Comment: There's a Source tab at the bottom of the editor you were opening.